# Halachah against dirty looks?

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics

Is there a halachah against giving people side-eyes/dirty looks? If memory serves this is in the Yom Kippur davening. What's the source?

If there is a prohibition, what's the exact character? Is one allowed to give fake dirty looks as one may feign anger but never actually be angry?

Comment: על חטא שחטאנו לפניך בעינים רמות... על חטא שחטאנו לפניך בשיקור עין

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%98%D7%96_%D7%94 תּוֹעֲבַת יְהוָה כָּל גְּבַהּ לֵב

Comment: Isn't this the Ayin HaRa?

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of in Tenach is

https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.18.28

> וְעֵינַיִם רָמוֹת תַּשְׁפִּיל
>
> but haughty eyes You humble.

From which we may infer a prohibition regarding haughty eyes.

Comment: Was looking at your other posts. This one is right up my alley. For me as perpetrator, not much distinction between tongue and eyes. Both with intent.